# How can I remove points from a matplotlib plot before plotting a new one?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, slider

I am trying to plot a point whose position is controlled by a slider. However, each time the slider is moved a new point is plotted without deleting the old one. How do you remove the old point before the new one is plotted?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

def on_change(val):
    point=ax.scatter(x[int(val)/1],y[int(val)/1],z[int(val)/1])

x=[0,0.5,1]
y=[0,0.5,1]
z=[0,0.5,1]
p=0
fig = pyplot.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],c='black',zorder=10)
point=ax.scatter(x[p],y[p],z[p],zorder=0)
ax.set_xlabel('Width')
ax.set_ylabel('Depth')
ax.set_zlabel('Height')
slider_ax = plt.axes([0.15, 0.05, 0.7, 0.02])
slider = Slider(slider_ax, "min", 0, 2, valinit=1, color='blue')
slider.on_changed(on_change)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: You're missing some imports. Please add them. Is plt pyplot? If so, then why do you also use pyplot? Usually people do from matplotlib import pyplot as plt but I'm not sure what your convention is.

Comment: I fixed the imports and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: But now others can run your code.
The issue is that you're drawing a subplot; usually, when you call plt.scatter, it returns a handle to the points drawn.
i.e. points = plt.scatter(whatever)
Here, you're calling scatter, but since it's a subplot, you're scattering on an axis. And the handle that the axis returns does not have a remove method.
You _could_ just try redrawing the entire thing. But that's not ideal. I'm seeing if I can figure something out.

Comment: @Daryl Not sure what you are talking about.  The `PathCollection` returned by `scatter` definitely has a `remove` method.

Comment: Hmm I guess the remove method didn't do anything for me when I tried it - at any rate HYRY probably has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the properties of `point`:

```
def on_change(val):
    point.set_offsets([x[int(val) / 1], y[int(val) / 1]])
    point.set_3d_properties([z[int(val) / 1]], "z")
    fig.canvas.draw()
```